# How to concatenate an array of matrices?

Tags: matrix, concatenation, join

When trying to concatenate matrices i usually use `Join`. But having the matrices in an array it gets tricky.

As an example:

```
 A = IdentityMatrix[2];
 B = 2*IdentityMatrix[2];
 mArray = {A,B};
```

I'd like to have something to obtain the same result of `Join[A,B,2]` (concatenating A with B on the right), while having the matrices on an array.

I tried something like `Apply[Join[#,2]&,mArray]` without luck.

Comment: `Join[##,2]&@@mArray` or `Join[Sequence @@ mArray, 2]`

Comment: `ArrayFlatten[{mArray}]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, i did not know about the slotsequence ##.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Catenate`:

```
Transpose@Catenate[mArray]

(*{{1, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 2}}*)
```